# Evaluating definite integrals whose limits are absolutely equal

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

The question that I'm stuck on reads as follows:

> The substitution rule can sometimes be used to simplify the evaluation
>   of an integral of an even or odd function. What can you say about the
>   integral $\int\limits_{-a}^a{f(x)dx}$ if
>
> a) $f$ is an even function
>
> b) $f$ is an odd function
>
> Give reasons for your answers.

I ignored the part about the substitution rule, and tried to prove for a) that $\int\limits_{-a}^a{f(x)dx}=2F(a)$ (which I assumed using common sense). However, my solution for a) consistently came out as 0. For example,

$\int\limits_{-a}^a{f(x)dx}=\int\limits_{-a}^0{f(x)dx}+\int\limits_{0}^a{f(x)dx}\\
=F(0)-F(-a)+F(a)-F(0)=-F(a)+F(a)=0$

$\ $

So, I then tried a Riemann sum:
$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{0-(-a)}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f\left(-a+\frac{0-(-a)i}{n}\right)}\right]+\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f\left(\frac{ai}{n}\right)}\right]\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(-a)+f\left(-a+\frac{a}{n}\right)+f\left(-a+\frac{2a}{n}\right)+...+f(-a+a)\right)\right]+\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(0)+f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{a(n-1)}{n}\right)+f(a)\right)\right]\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(0)-f(0)+f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+...+f\left(a-\frac{a}{n}\right)-f\left(a-\frac{a}{n}\right)+f(a)-f(a)\right)\right]\\
=0$

$\ $

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well for one thing, your LaTeX is all messed up!

Comment: Ugh!? Your post hurts my eyes.

Comment: Sorry. It's my first time on this site. Does [tex] [/tex] not work? I don't know how to do previews either.

Comment: @user151595 No, just replace all the [tex] and [/tex] by $'s.

Comment: The second-last equality is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $$\int\limits_{-a}^a{f(x)dx}=\int\limits_{-a}^0{f(x)dx}=\int\limits_{0}^a{f(x)dx}\\
=F(0)-F(-a)+F(a)-F(0)=-F(a)+F(a)=0$$  is false because it is the **integrand** $f(x)$ that is even, *not* its antiderivative $F(x)$.  That is to say, $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ does not imply that $F(x) = F(-x)$ where $F$ is a function that satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$.  Rather, you should write with the substitution $u = -x$, $du = -dx$, $$\int_{x=-a}^0 f(x) \, dx = \int_{u=a}^0 f(-u) \, (-du) = \int_{u=0}^a f(-u) \, du = \int_{u=0}^a f(u) \, du,$$ and the only place where we use the evenness of $f$ is in the rightmost equality above.

Comment: I don't understand why $f(x)=f(−x)$  for all $x \in \mathbb R$  does not imply that $F(x)=F(−x)$ where $F$ is the anti-derivative of $f$. If I draw a graph of $f(x)=x^2$, the area will be the same on either side of the origin.



I used your method on the integral 
$\int\limits_0^a{f(x)dx}$ 
and got 
$\int\limits_{-a}^0{f(u)du}$, 
so I added them to get $\int\limits_{-a}^a{f(u)du}=\int\limits_{a}^{-a}{f(x)dx}$.


Do you think that is the answer they are looking for?



I also used the same method on b), and got the same answer of

$\int\limits_{a}^{-a}{f(x)dx}$.

Comment: For example:  $f(x) = 1$ satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$, but the antiderivative $F(x) = x$ does not satisfy $F(x)=F(-x)$.

Comment: The second equals sign should be a $+$. I [recommended](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/223602) an edit two years ago, but it was incorrectly rejected.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake across the second-last equality of my Riemann sum:

$=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(-a)+f\left(-a+\frac{a}{n}\right)+f\left(-a+\frac{2a}{n}\right)+...+f(-a+a)\right)\right]+\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(0)+f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{a(n-1)}{n}\right)+f(a)\right)\right]\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{a}{n}\left(f(0)+f(0)+f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+...+f\left(a-\frac{a}{n}\right)+f\left(a-\frac{a}{n}\right)+f(a)+f(a)\right)\right]\\
=2\displaystyle\int_0^a f(x) dx$